# C++ Dictionary Compare with multiple strings and files

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, vector, io

I am trying to write a program that will compare an input file to a dictionary file filled with tons of words. After comparing the words, I want to output the words that are spelled incorrectly. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void trim(string s)
{
    size_t p = s.find_first_not_of(" \t");
    s.erase(0, p);
    p = s.find_last_not_of(" \t");
    if (string::npos != p)
        s.erase(p+1);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    ifstream words;

    input.open("/Users/jordan/Desktop/CS60/Word_dictionary_check/input.txt");
    if(input.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Input file opening failed";
        exit(1);
    }
    words.open("/Users/jordan/Desktop/CS60/Word_dictionary_check/words.txt");
    if(words.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Words file opening failed";
    }

    vector <string> wordCheck;
    vector <string> misspelledWord;
    string temp = "";

    while(!input.eof())
    {
        input>>temp;
        wordCheck.push_back(temp);

    }

    ofstream output;
    output.open("/Users/jordan/Desktop/CS60/Word_dictionary_check/output.txt");
    if(output.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Output file opening failed";
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < wordCheck.size(); j++)
    {
        bool dontprint = false;
        while(!words.eof())
        {
            words>>temp;
            if(temp == wordCheck[j])
            {
                dontprint = true;
            }

        }
        if(dontprint == false)
        {
            misspelledWord.push_back(wordCheck[j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < misspelledWord.size() ; i++)
    {

        output<<misspelledWord[i]<<endl;

    }

    return 0;


}
```

I believe something with whitespace or with the comparing of strings is a problem.  Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If you're going to dump homework you must give a less vague [problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I can see few obvious problems. I have added comments. This should solve your problem  but I am not going to write code for you.

```
for(int j = 0; j < wordCheck.size(); j++)
{
    bool dontprint = false;

    //Make your words file pointer to point to start of file. USe seek function
    while(!words.eof())
    {
        words>>temp;
        if(temp == wordCheck[j])
        {
            dontprint = true;
            //You can break here. As once word is found, you don't need to check the word file further
        }

    }
    if(dontprint == false)
    {
        misspelledWord.push_back(wordCheck[j]);
    }
}
```